# Create GATT Server with Micropython on Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, micropython, bluetooth-gatt, raspberry-pi-pico

I want to create a simple GATT Server on my Raspberry Pi Pico. The goal is to create a service that sends a simple set of data to the client. Im using the latest version of MicroPython. My Problem is, that I cant seem to figure out how I can use the MicroPython-specific bluetooth library (https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/bluetooth.html), because it doesnt seem to be accesible on the Raspnerry Pi Pico. I also tried using standard python librarys like the bluez-peripheral (https://github.com/spacecheese/bluez_peripheral), but there were a lot of modules missing, that I wasnt able to install. Im open to using any other library. It would be great if someone would know how I can get these librarys running on my Pico or has any suggestions for other librarys. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I've just had a look at the Pico's specification and it doesn't seem to have any Bluetooth hardware on https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/raspberry-pi-pico.html. You will need to add an additional module. A quick search of the internet has return some tutorials of how to do this.

Comment: The Arduino guys have already done this: https://store.arduino.cc/products/arduino-nano-rp2040-connect-with-headers
Needless to say that it supports python :-) https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/nano-rp2040-connect

Comment: Forgot to mention that. I already connected an hc08 module.

Comment: If you have an HC-08 attached then you don't need the Bluetooth libraries. You communicate with it via UART. e.g. http://helloraspberrypi.blogspot.com/2021/02/raspberry-pi-picomicropython-hc-08-ble.html